# Google Image Search API Max Result Size

Tags: java, rest, google-api

I'm trying to use the google rest api, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=monkey&rsz=8 as described [api spec here](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.htm).  It looks like 8 results is the max and that just doesn't seem sensible to me.  Am I missing something?  I'm able to append rsz=8 parameter but can't go any higher than 8 or the api returns an error response. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 Thanx C12 for your URL, by this i came to know about Result size we can get by using 'rsz'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the rest api you will get 8 results per page and a maximum of 20 pages.

Answer (score 0):

google limits you for 'performance' reasons. If there was no limit their servers would get hammered